# scrollView内のeditTextのフォーカスを外したい

Tags: android, java, xml

ScrollViewを使わなければ、EditTextにフォーカスされていても、画面のEditText部以外をタップすればEditTextのフォーカスがはずれます。しかし、LinearLayoutの中にScrollViewを入れると、ScrollView内のEditTextのフォーカスを外せなくなってしまいます。どうすれば、ScrollView内でもフォーカスを外せるようにできるのでしょうか？

ご教示よろしくお願い致します。

android studioを使用しています。

xmlです。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout3">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

javaです。

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// キーボード表示を制御するためのオブジェクト
public InputMethodManager inputMethodManager1;
// 背景のレイアウト
private LinearLayout mainLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // キーボード表示を制御するためのオブジェクト
    inputMethodManager1 = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout3);

}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // キーボードを隠す
    inputMethodManager1.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mainLayout.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    // 背景にフォーカスを移す
    mainLayout.requestFocus();

    return true;

}
}
```

回答ありがとうございます。ご教示のとおりにScrollViewに`android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"`を追加しました。
確かにScrollView外の"Hello World"をタップするとフォーカスが外れてキーボードが消えますが、ScrollView内の"Hello World"をタップしてもフォーカスが外れませんでした。キーボードもそのまま表示されています。私の説明不足ですみません。ScrollView内の別の部位（例えばTextView）をタップしてもフォーカスを外してキーボードを消したいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout`の`ScrollView`ので`android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"`を追加する。